# Pure C++ program compiled for Android

Tags: android, android-ndk

I want to compile this program for Android and see it run on my phone:

```
#include "Hello World.h"

using namespace codewerks;

//=============================================
// Main Loop
//=============================================
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
        Print(std::string("Hello World!"));
}
```

Where do I start?  Can I compile this with GCC?  The NDK seems focused on Java.  Thank you.

Comment: Please read the android developer pages on the NDK. You can not, at this time, compile and run Native only code on Android.

Comment: Where exactly do you expect Hello World to print on the phone? You need to read up on the android framework

Comment: Supposedly this is possible with C4Droid but I have not tried it. There's also a gcc plugin for it.

Answer (score 4):

This is now possible with the latest NDK. You will need an emulator or phone running Android 2.3 to try it, but the [NativeActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NativeActivity.html) documentation has a complete example.

Unfortunately it is somewhat more complicated than a simple "hello world" example, and "main" is spelled "android_main". You still need to worry about your application life cycle as you do in Java, and the only real way to draw to the screen is to use OpenGL ES. It seems to be designed for writing games for Android.

Answer (score 2):

Build as executable. (BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
Copy the executable to sdcard. (adb push)
Go to android shell. (adb shell)
Change the permission of the executable. (chmod 777)
Run the executable. (./out)
You will see the printed result on the console. (happy?)

Comment: How exactly does one build this executable?

Comment: include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
Write this at the end of the Android.mk file

Comment: Could you be more specific?  Like what compiler options are needed ect.

Comment: `/sdcard` does not have execute permissions, you need another place, e.g. `/data/local/tmp`